# React Router Not Working Like I Need It Too

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Im trying to figure out how to get my navigation bar setup as most of the UI is coming together. I have setup my index.js and also a Route.js and then linked them with my different components like so:

Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Auth0Provider } from "./react-auth0-spa.js";
import { useAuth0 } from "./react-auth0-spa";
import Routes from "./Routes"
import config from "./utils/auth_config.json";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";


// A function that routes the user to the right place
// after login
const onRedirectCallback = appState => {
  history.push(
    appState && appState.targetUrl
      ? appState.targetUrl
      : window.location.pathname
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Auth0Provider
    domain={config.domain}
    client_id={config.clientId}
    redirect_uri={window.location.origin}
    onRedirectCallback={onRedirectCallback}
  >
  <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes />
  </BrowserRouter>

  </Auth0Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

Routes.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Router, Route, Switch, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import {Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Profile from "./components/user/Profile";
import PrivateRoute from "./components/user/PrivateRoute";
import history from "./utils/history.js";
import HomePage from "./modules/HomePage.js";
import ProductPage from "./modules/ProductPage";

class Routes extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={history}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
                    <Route path="/ProductPage" component={ProductPage} />
                    <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>    
        )
    }
}

export default Routes;
```

but when i reload my site it just continues to say localhost:8080/ProductPage like its suppose to be the default, then when i manually enter localhost:8080/ and click on a button after linking it with

```
<Link to="ProductPage">
```

it will show on the tab localhost:8080/ProductPage but wont actually redirect me to the other component, i am just wondering what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You are using `Browser Router` and a `Router` try to use one only,

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

You have your "home" route listed first in the [Switch](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Switch).

Switch

> Renders the ***first*** child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the location.

"/" is less specific and matches basically all routes, so even though the URL is "/ProductPage", "/" still matches it and `HomePage` is rendered.

## Solution

Either move it after the other more specific routes or use the `exact` prop on it.

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/ProductPage" component={ProductPage} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
    <Route path="/" component={HomePage} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

or

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
    <Route path="/ProductPage" component={ProductPage} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={Profile} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```